# How to copy a piece of texture on MonoGame Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, monogame, texture2d

I used this code to copy a piece of texture to another texture , it did work on Windows , but on Android it didn't . How can i fix it ?

Here my code :

```
public int DerivationGraph(int SrcX, int SrcY, int Width, int Height, int SrcGraphHandle)
    {
        Texture2D originalTexture = _textureCache[SrcGraphHandle];
        Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(SrcX, SrcY, Width, Height);

        Texture2D cropTexture = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, sourceRectangle.Width, sourceRectangle.Height);
        Color[] data = new Color[sourceRectangle.Width * sourceRectangle.Height];
        originalTexture.GetData(0, sourceRectangle, data, 0, data.Length);
        cropTexture.SetData(data);
        int nextIndex = textureIndex + 1;
        _textureCache[nextIndex] = cropTexture;

        textureIndex++;
        return textureIndex;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into the same thing, and unfortunately it appears that the particular overload that uses a source rectangle simply does not work.  From what I have found, the problem comes from OpenGL ES-2.0 not supporting reads after video memory has been loaded.

From this [discussion](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/issues/1405) on the MonoGame Develop branch:

> tomspilman commented on Feb 19, 2013
>
> **you could not read back texture data once it was uploaded to video memory**

That particular discussion is about the iOS implementation of GetData(), but it makes mention of the Android overloads and there being a workaround involved in getting it to work.

Personally, I have tried the [generic method for GetData()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197089.aspx) on Android and it does in fact work. The [source rectangle method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197084.aspx), however, does not return any data using OpenGL ES 1.1 or 2.0.

Getting the entire texture data may be your only solution.